# How to grant or update the 'createsecureauth' privilege in db2 syscat.dbauth table?

Tags: security, db2

With the following DB2 query, I can view the 'CREATESECUREAUTH' privilege:

```
select grantee, granteetype, createsecureauth from syscat.dbauth
```

The above query result:

```
GRANTEE     GRANTEETYPE     CREATESECUREAUTH
--------------------------------------------
DB2INST     U       N
```

Now I want to update the createsecureauth privilege from 'N' to 'Y' for grantee 'DB2INST'
But I cannot do that with 'GRANT' or 'UPDATE'.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That privilege is called differently, check the [GRANT syntax](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000958.html):

```
GRANT CREATE_SECURE_OBJECT ON DATABASE TO USER HENRIK
```

The privilege allows to create secure objects, i.e., secure triggers and secure functions.

Comment: Thanks this is working. Can you tell me how to grant 'LIBRARYADMAUTH' authority as well? I can't grant this one too.

Comment: See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001041.html: "Reserved for future use"

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find all the keywords like 'CREATE_SECURE_OBJECT' for 'CREATESECUREAUTH'. I need to grant multiple such privileges like 'EXPLAINAUTH', 'SQLADMAUTH', etc.

Comment: See the two links that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

The following SQL maps the columns of `SYSCAT.DBAUTH` to the names of the privileges used in GRANT (or REVOKE) statements

```
SELECT A.GRANTEE        AS AUTHID
,      A.GRANTEETYPE    AS AUTHIDTYPE
,      B.PRIVILEGE
,      CASE WHEN B.AUTH = 'G' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS GRANTABLE
,      CURRENT SERVER   AS OBJECTNAME
,      ''               AS OBJECTSCHEMA
,      CAST ('DATABASE' AS VARCHAR (11)) AS OBJECTTYPE
FROM SYSCAT.DBAUTH A          
, LATERAL(VALUES
    (BINDADDAUTH         ,'BINDADD')
,   (CONNECTAUTH         ,'CONNECT')
,   (CREATETABAUTH       ,'CREATETAB')
,   (DBADMAUTH           ,'DBADM')
,   (EXTERNALROUTINEAUTH ,'CREATE_EXTERNAL_ROUTINE')
,   (IMPLSCHEMAAUTH      ,'IMPLICIT_SCHEMA')      
,   (LOADAUTH            ,'LOAD')
,   (NOFENCEAUTH         ,'CREATE_NOT_FENCED_ROUTINE') 
,   (QUIESCECONNECTAUTH  ,'QUIESCE_CONNECT')
,   (LIBRARYADMAUTH      ,'LIBRARYADMAUTH')
,   (SECURITYADMAUTH     ,'SECADM')
,   (SQLADMAUTH          ,'SQLADM')
,   (WLMADMAUTH          ,'WLMADM')
,   (EXPLAINAUTH         ,'EXPLAIN')
,   (DATAACCESSAUTH      ,'DATAACCESS')
,   (ACCESSCTRLAUTH      ,'ACCESSCTRL')
) B ( AUTH, PRIVILEGE )
WHERE  B.AUTH IN ('Y','G')
```